# how to save changes to data provider?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I have a data grid with editable option set to true. When I make changes to the data the changes should apply to the data provider of spark data grid. I am new to flex can any one help me out.

Comment: Please put the code (if it can), maybe your dataprovider is not correctly binded.

Answer (score 0):

Use CollectionChangeEvent

do a check on event.kind == CollectionEventKind.UPDATE It is dispatched when a value is changed on the grid .

It has all the information about the changed object & before and after change values .
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=about_dataproviders_5.html